# Why is there 1 binary bracketing when n = 1?

Tags: combinatorics, binary-operations, catalan-numbers

My professor gave a question that started with:
Imagine a unary alphabet with a single letter x. A (valid) bracketing B is a string over three symbols x, (, ) defined recursively as follows: (1) a single letter x is a bracketing, and (2) for any k >= 2, if B1,...,Bk are (valid) bracketings, then so is B = (B1B2...Bk). A bracketing B is called
binary if rule (2) can only be applied with k = 2. Then length n of B is the number of x's it has(i.e., one ignores the parenthesis).

In his solution, he started out with "For n = 1, there is clearly only one binary bracketing."

My searches online led me to learn that it was related to Catalan Parantheses, which did not have "x". In the Catalan Parantheses, there was only 1 way to arrange 1 pair of brackets correctly: (). Using n-1 for the Catalan binomial coefficients also give a result of 1.

However, my searches online also led me to see the binary bracketings as bracketings that can be "resolved" with only binary operators. (xx)(xx) -> (y)(y) -> z all use binary operators, but (xx)xx -> yxx -> z would need a ternary operator.

Why is there 1 *binary bracketing* when n = 1 instead of 0 *binary* bracketings? How do you feed a single input into a *binary* operator? If "A bracketing B is called *binary* if rule (2) can only be applied with k = 2.", then why does n = 1 have a *binary* bracketing if k = 1 for n = 1? Is this a $2^0$ = 1 thing?

Comment: Remember rule (1) in your recursive definition.  Just $x$ by itself counts as a bracketing, despite not using any parentheses.

Comment: But why is it a _binary_ bracketing?

Comment: "A bracketing B is called binary if rule (2) can only be applied with $k = 2$." Not applying rule (2) at all constitutes only applying it with $k=2$.

Comment: Does that not mean that if rule(2) cannot be applied with k = 2, then a single x is just a valid bracketing but not a _binary_ bracketing?

Comment: That is not how your recursive definition of binary bracketings works.  Rule (1) is the base case of the definition.  Without it there would not be a justification for any binary bracketings at all.  The recursion starts there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of a string in the ternary alphabet is the number of $x$s it contains, so the string
$$ x  $$
is the only bracketing with one $x$.  It *is* a bracketing by rule 1: "a single letter $x$ is a bracketing".  No other string constructed by rules 1 and 2 has only one $x$, though this takes a few steps to show.  Let $\ell(B)$ denote the length of $B$.  Rule 1 gives us $B = x$ with $\ell(B) = 1$.  Rule 2 (in the binary case) gives us $B = (B_1 B_2)$, as long as $B_1$ and $B_2$ are valid binary bracketings, with $\ell(B) = \ell(B_1) + \ell(B_2)$.  As a consequence, $\ell(B) \geq \ell(B_1)$, with equality only if $\ell(B_2) = 0$, and similarly $\ell(B) \geq \ell(B_2)$.  So rule 1 gives us a binary bracketing of length $1$ and rule $2$ gives us binary bracketings at least as long as the shorter of the $B_1$ and $B_2$ used to construct it.  This means there are no $0$ length binary bracketings.  Therefore, use of rule 2 *strictly* increases the length of a binary bracketing, eliminating the possibility of other binary bracketings having length $1$.  Therefore, there is only one binary bracketing having length $1$ and it is $x$.

Notice that rule 2 also guarantees that any $B$ with $\ell(B) > 1$ has at least one pair of opening and closing parentheses.  This means $xx$ is not a binary bracketing produced by rules 1 and 2 and neither is any longer string of $x$s without brackets.

It might help to realize that, relative to the references you are reading about Catalan Parentheses, the symbol "$x$" used here represents an empty pair of parentheses "$()$".  If you picture a bracketing as a fork in a tree, the whole bracketing corresponds to the base of the tree, where it meets the ground.  Since we only apply rule 2 with $k=2$, every fork is 2-way, that is, it is a binary fork.  Then the outermost application of rule 2 gives the first forking to two branches.  Nested applications of rule 2 give further forkings.  All binary bracketing forkings eventually terminate with "$x$"s and all Catalan Parentheses forkings eventually terminate with "$()$"s.  These two substrings are serving similar purposes in the two problems.

Regarding the operators re-setting of the problem.  Definitely, "$(xx)xx$" requires a ternary operator.    Since $xx$ is not a valid binary bracketing by rules 1 and 2, we must have 
$$  \underbrace{(xx)}_{B_1} \underbrace{x}_{B_2} \underbrace{x}_{B_3}  \text{,}  $$
which is not a binary bracketing.  This does require that $k = 3$ be permitted in rule 2, which is not the case for binary bracketing.

Comment: Does that not mean that if rule(2) cannot be applied with k = 2, then a single x(n = 1) is just a valid bracketing but not a _binary_ bracketing, since in this case $B = (B_1)$?

Comment: @JCosmeo : I don't understand this question.  "$x$" is a valid binary bracketing because rule 1 says it is.  All *binary* bracketing does is restrict rule 2, requiring $k = 2$; this in no way alters rule 1.

Comment: Rule 1 states that "x" is a valid bracketing, but _binary_ was not mentioned in rule 1 until after rule 2. I'm confused about whether the exclusion of the word _binary_ changes anything, because it sounds as if a ternary bracketing is a valid bracketing but not a **valid** _and_ **binary** bracketing.

Comment: Do not think of the rules as separable.  Rule 1 + rule 2 is a bracketing.  Rule 1 + rule 2 with the constraint $k=2$ is a binary bracketing.  Rule 1 + rule 2 with the constraint $k=3$ is a ternary bracketing.  A definition by a set of rules takes all the rules together.  If one wants to make a definition by forgetting a rule, one must explicitly say so.

Comment: So if Rule 1 + rule 2 with the constraint k=2 is a binary bracketing, then any valid bracketing **must** also be a _binary_ bracketing? If it was originally Rule 1 + rule 2 with the constraint k=3, then any valid bracketing **must** also be a _ternary_ bracketing?

Comment: @JCosmeo : No.  There are valid bracketings that are not binary bracketings.  Any valid bracketing has applications of rule 2 with any value of $k$, including values of $k$ other than $2$.  Any valid binary bracketing has applications of rule 2 only with the value $k=2$.  Any valid ternary bracketing has applications of rule 2 only with the value $k=3$.  The base definition is for a "bracketing" and does not specify an arity (binary, ternary, et c.).

Comment: Since _Any valid binary bracketing has applications of rule 2 only with the value k=2._, then why is "x" a **binary** bracket if k is only 1 for n = 1?

If n = 2, then $B = (B_1 B_2)$ where $B_1$ = "x" and $B_2$ = "x".

But if n = 1, then isn't there only $B_1$ and no $B_2$? Which two valid bracket combines to form a binary $B$ when there is only 1 "x" at n = 1?

Comment: $k$ is not $1$ for $n=1$.  "$x$" is a binary bracket because rule 1 says it is, entirely independently of any restriction on $k$ in rule 2.  "$x$" is a bracket, a binary bracket, a ternary bracket, a mixed binary and ternary bracket, and every other choice of arity constraint.  Rule 1 is present and unchanged for all choices of restriction on $k$, so "$x$" is a bracket for all choices of restriction on $k$.

Comment: @JCosmeo : It may benefit you to explicitly write down the complete set of rules for a bracket, the complete set of rules for a binary bracket, the complete set of rules for a ternary bracket, and the complete set of rules for a $2 \leq k \leq 4$ bracket.  You seem to be blurring the rules among the several definitions and seem unclear that rule 1 is present in every such list of rules.